# Container with 3 borders and radiuses

Tags: flutter, containers

I'm looking for the way to create rounded container with only **topLeft and topRight** radiuses and **without** bottom border. Here is what I tried:

```
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                            left: BorderSide(
                              color: AppColors.lightPurple2,
                            ),
                            right: BorderSide(
                              color: AppColors.lightPurple2,
                            ),
                            top: BorderSide(
                              color: AppColors.lightPurple2,
                            ),
                          ),
                          // border: Border.all(
                          //   color: AppColors.lightPurple2,
                          // ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(Rad.sm),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(Rad.sm),
                          ),
                        ),
```

But this code doesn't work

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during paint():
A borderRadius can only be given for a uniform Border.

The following is not uniform:
BorderSide.color
BorderSide.width
BorderSide.style
```

However if I use *Border.all()* it works good but I need to remove bottom border somehow.
If I remove *borderRadius* it draw 3 border but without radiuses.

So is there a way to use both options?

What I want to get eventually:
[image: What I want to get eventually]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a colored bottom border on a rounded corner Container in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58113983/how-to-add-a-colored-bottom-border-on-a-rounded-corner-container-in-flutter)

Comment: Can you add an image of what you are trying to create please?

Comment: Ivo, thanks. but not really. I need a border 3 side, Clip doesn't solve that

Comment: @Kaushik Chandru sure, just edited

Comment: is that the attached image you are trying to archive
?

Comment: Yes that is what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use shadow and achieve the same result

```
 Container(
                height: 300,
                width: 300,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(10)),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.purple,
                          offset: Offset(2, -2),
                          spreadRadius: 0,
                          blurRadius: 0),
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.purple,
                          offset: Offset(-2, -2),
                          spreadRadius: 0,
                          blurRadius: 0)
                    ]))
```

[image: preview]